# Krull-Dimension of $k[X, Y , Z]/(Y-Z^2, XZ-Y^2)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, polynomial-rings

I am supposed to compute the krull-dimension of $k[X, Y, Z]/(Y-Z^2, XZ-Y^2)$, where $k$ is a field, and feel quite at sea, as we have only looked at principal ideals and obvious applications of the noether normalization lemma.
How can I approach this?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $k[X,Y,Z]/(Y-Z^2,XZ-Y^2)$? Looking at the variety associated to that ideal, I think you should be able to prove the ring is of dimension $1$.

Comment: Here is a hint, which is a useful technique for calculating in polynomial rings in general: If one variable appears by itself as a term in one of the generators, you can "solve" for it and eliminate it from your variable list. So make this a quotient by a single polynomial of $k[X,Z]$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction and thank you both for the hints.

Comment: So $k[X,Y,Z]/(Y-Z^2, XZ-Y^2) \cong k[X,Z]/(X(Z-X^3))$ and because $k[X,Z]/(X(Z-X^3))$ is integral over $k[Z]$ and a $k[Z]$-Algebra of finite Type, it is of dimension 1?

Comment: I would just count chains of primes: Both $(Z)$ and $(X-Z^3)$ are minimal primes (as they consist of zero-divisors)...